# Convert DB TimeStamp to Time Ago

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pulling a `timeStamp` from the database that basically has a value similar to this `2020-08-13 21:51:50`, is there a way to convert this `timeStamp` to time ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [timeago](https://pub.dev/packages/timeago) package.

```dart
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;

print(timeago.format(DateTime.parse('2020-08-13 21:51:50')));
```

Answer (score 0):

JideGuru is correct on how to use the timeago package; however, if you are pulling the timestamp from a MySQL database you may need to convert it to `toDate` first:

```dart
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;

var rawTime = mySQLTimestamp.toDate();
String timeAgoTime = timeago.format(rawTime);
```

Comment: actually JideGuru code works fine for me, I didn't have to convert it toDate. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: The question state's that the timestamp value looks like this `2020-08-13 21:51:50`. so there's no need for `.toDate` because you only need to convert the string to DateTime like this `DateTime.parse('2020-08-13 21:51:50')`